# How to modify this SearchAndReplace routine to work with large files

Tags: c#, performance, file-io, large-files

I would like to modify the following code to work with large files.

```
    public static void Replace(string filePath, string searchText, string replaceText)
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
        string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();

        content = Regex.Replace(content, searchText, replaceText);

        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath);
        writer.Write(content);
        writer.Close();
    }
```

I'm thinking that I'm going to need to open a filestream to write to a new file name, and then delete the original file and replace it with the new one when I'm done.  Does that sound about right?

Also...
I love the simplicity of this routine, that aside from the necessary file i/o lines of code there is only one line of code to process the file.  However, I'm also wondering if I'm sacrificing performance for simplicity... is Regex.Replace very performant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**: you can try **`Regex with Stream`** (it seems be more faster and less memory requirement):

- [Building a Regular Expression Stream Search with the .NET Framework](http://www.developer.com/design/article.php/3719741/Building-a-Regular-Expression-Stream-Search-with-the-NET-Framework.htm)

or see **`Mono-Project Regex`**. It has Regex with streaming.

see this article for Regex performance:

- [C# Regex Performance](http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-performance) (from *dotnetperls*)

or if using `Regex` is not necessary use `String.Replace` and try this one line code:

```
File.WriteAllText(filePath, 
                  File.ReadAllText(filePath).Replace(searchText, replaceText));
```

Comment: Isn't ReadAllText going to read the entire file into memory?  The main part of this question was about modifying this to work with large files, because I get a memory exception trying to load an entire file at once.

Comment: @BrandonMoore: and also I suggested `Regex with Stream`

Answer (score 1):

One way you can speed up a Regex is to pass the RegexOptions.Compiled option, which will take your regex and compile the state machine down to IL. This has some overhead for the compile step, but once it's compiled the regex would execute faster. Obviously you should time your code to see whether Regex compilation helps or hurts your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without regex too using the [File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z2ck8eh) class

```
public static void Replace(string filePath, string searchText, string replaceText)
{
   string newText = File.ReadAllText(filePath).Replace(searchText, replaceText));
   File.Delete(filePath);
   File.WriteAllText(newFilePath, newText);
}
```

Comment: You might have overlooked the main issue, which is that I need this to work with large files.  ReadToEnd is giving me a memory exception, and I'm guessing ReadAllText is going to do the same.

Comment: @BrandonMoore try this else i will give you another solution that will not be consume all lot of memory at one time